# When can Playwright's Page.ViewportSize be null?

Tags: playwright, playwright-dotnet

The `Page.ViewportSize` property is [defined as nullable](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-viewport-size).

Under what conditions could it be null?

Comment: What is the exact playwright issue you are facing?

Comment: No issue. I want to know when it can be null. I don't want unexpected NREs. I don't understand how it could ever be null, and yet it was annotated that way for a reason.

Comment: Ok, I dug up the docs and provided some info.Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Viewport: null is mainly for headful / interactive mode . It simply means that the user would set the viewport size via resizing the window.**

[NOTE](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-viewport):
The null value opts out from the default presets, makes viewport depend on the host window size defined by the operating system. It makes the execution of the tests non-deterministic.

Code Example:

```
const playwright = require('playwright');

    (async () => {
      for (const browserType of ['chromium', 'firefox', 'webkit']) {
        const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
        const context = await browser.newContext({
          viewport: null
        });
        const page = await context.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://google.com');
        
       
        await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${browserType}.png` });
        await browser.close();
      }
    })();
```

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/2170

Comment: There is another case where it's null, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another case where it's null:

From one of the maintainers on the [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/22316#issuecomment-1502317059):

> ConnectOverCDP and if you pass no viewport on context creation are such scenarios where its null.